# Usercontrol is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I'm create a popup in wp8 where another usercontrol i call this popup on button click below the code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Mypopup.VerticalOffset = 100;


        if (Mypopup.IsOpen != true)
        {
            Mypopup.Child = Mycontrol;
            Mypopup.IsOpen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Mypopup.IsOpen = false;
        }

        Mycontrol.Settings.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                Mycontrol.Settings.NavigateUri = new Uri("/SelectJokeType.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            };      
 }
```

But NavigateUri is not working it's not go to Selectjoketype.xaml page

Comment: If i use this                                   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SelectJokeType.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));  it's will show error

Answer (score 0):

What about NavigationService.Navigate? additional information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SelectJokeType.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   This mesage show object refference instance (Null message)

Comment: try to use this code - ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(URL);

Comment: nikolay can u explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for Silverlight for Windows Phone 8:

```
 public Page Page { get; set; }
 this.Loaded += delegate
{
    Page = (Application.Current.RootVisual as Frame).Content as Page;
};
Page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/mainpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```